# Trying to get the latest stable release v5.11.0 of Servicestack working with our classic ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I am trying to upgrade our classic ASP.NET application all the way from ServiceStack 3.9.64 to the latest version 5.11.0. The app serves BOTH ASPX pages and ServiceStack API calls. I have a lot of code that relies upon `HttpContext.Current` being available in the context of an ASP.NET application regardless of whether or not an ASPX page is being hit, or a ServiceStack route is being hit. Up until now this has always worked.

This example here: https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/Server.AspNet shows what for me is a very **incomplete** example of global.asax.cs. The usual `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` methods are entirely missing! This would seem to suggest that ServiceStack is now doing entirely it's own thing under the covers that is divorced from the `HttpContext.Current` singleton that we have been relying upon.

How do I address this without threading an HttpContextBase or HttpRequestBase object all through my code? Our ASP.NET app of course handles many concurrent HTTP requests and does so in the ASP.NET-style 'thread safe' manner, where we never use the [ThreadStatic] attribute. We rely upon HttpContext.Current singleton to do that for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `Global.asax` is to enable ASP.NET Apps to hook into different lifecycle events of an ASP.NET Web Application. The lack of event hook implementations does not in any way indicate that an ASP.NET App is incomplete or presumes any behavior of the functionality of an ASP.NET App other than it does not need or rely on those life cycle events. It certainly doesn't suggest anything about an App being "divorced from the HttpContext.Current singleton" which isn't possible in ASP.NET Apps since it's automatically populated by the ASP.NET Framework before it invokes an Apps ASP.NET Handler.

Only the `Application_Start` event is implemented because that's the only event a ServiceStack ASP.NET App requires in order to initialize your ServiceStack `AppHost` when an ASP.NET Application is started:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new AppHost().Init();
}
```

The `HttpContext.Current` singleton is available in all **ASP.NET Framework Web Applications** which is always populated in the Request Worker thread of an ASP.NET Request. ServiceStack Services are no exception since they're run on an ASP.NET Request Worker thread as normal so if you run the [Server.AspNet](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/Server.AspNet) you linked to and put a break point on a Service implementation you will be able to inspect the populated `HttpContext.Current` singleton as normal:

[image]

The main reason why the `HttpContext.Current` singleton isn't populated in ASP.NET Framework Apps is if it's not being accessed in an ASP.NET Request Worker thread, e.g. if it was accessed from a Background Thread instead.

If you were instead referring to ASP.NET Sessions which ServiceStack doesn't use, they would need to be [enabled with a Session HttpHandler Factory](https://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework#enable-aspnet-sessions).

Comment: We are using AppHostBase, and according to other articles I've read ServiceStack does not spawn any background threads of it's own. So, there should be no situation at all where HttpContext.Current isn't populated. I will continue investigating that to see if there's a problem in our code.

Is there a way to configure our AppHostBase to directly invoke BeginRequest and EndRequest methods on Global.asax.cs? That would allow us to get back to the flow that's been working for us for years with older versions of ServiceStack.

Comment: You can still register and handle all ASP.NET Global.asax events like any ASP.NET App, all these events are still fired by ASP.NET Framework. ServiceStack includes a number of request filters and handlers for intercepting ServiceStack requests that’s documented in https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations

Comment: I will post my order of operations problem to a new question.

Comment: @KevinMacDonald is it null in a Service? If you can provide a standalone repro on GitHub that I can run locally to repro the issue I can take a look

Comment: That's going to be a very lengthy repro. See my other question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776049/servicestack-order-of-operations-problem-during-the-execution-of-a-service. 

I think my problem boils down to this. My Auth Plugin as configured in AppHost.Configured is invoked BEFORE AppHost.OnPreExecuteServiceFilter is fired, which means I don't get a chance to do necessary initializations. Can I turn that order around? If I can I think I will have solved my problem. I