# ServiceStack order of operations problem during the execution of a Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

We are upgrading our classic ASP.NET application for ServiceStack v5.11.0 from v3.9.64 and are eager to become a paying customer of ServiceStack. But we must resolve this problem. The lifecycle and order of operations has changed in ServiceStack. There are certain points in the lifecycle of a request as handled by ServiceStack where `HttpContext.Current` is not yet populated. All of our code expects that to be set up, so we must avoid that in our processing or a request. Below is the order of operations that we think we need.

1. First, `HttpContext.Current` must be populated by the system.
2. Next, we need an event to fire on our `AppHost : AppHostBase` that allows us to initialize our middle tier. We are currently trying AppHost.OnPreExecuteServiceFilter, but this is proving problematic due to the invocation of Plugins. Please read on.
3. Next, we have a Plugin we have written to do authentication that is added to Plugins in AppHost.Configure. We need this to be invoked AFTER Step 2.
4. Then we want our Service code to be invoked.
5. Finally, we need AppHost.OnEndRequest to be invoked.

The problem we face above is that our authentication Plugin is being invoked BEFORE AppHost.OnPreExecuteServiceFilter, and so our code fails because we have not initialized our middle tier yet. So Step 2 and 3 are occurring in the wrong order currently. How do we fix this? Is there a different AppHost event that is fired after HttpContext.Current is populated, and before Plugins are invoked? Or can we configure our plugin to be invoked just after AppHost.OnPreExecuteServiceFilter?

Further notes on this. With v3.9.64 our Global.Application_BeginRequest and EndRequest events were being used for the above purpose, and that was always working fine. I do see that these events are fired upon an incoming ServiceStack request, but they are not happening in the same order they used to, thus we face this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Order of Operations](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) is simply the order in which different hooks and filters are executed within a ServiceStack Request.

`OnPreExecuteServiceFilter` is as the name says a filter that's executed just before a Service is executed.

> Next, we have a Plugin we have written to do authentication that is added to Plugins in AppHost.Configure. We need this to be invoked AFTER Step 2.

`AppHost.Configure()` is executed only once on Startup for the purposes of configuring your AppHost. If you want your Plugin to execute logic during a request it needs to register a Custom Filter that's executed within the [ServiceStack Request Pipeline](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations).

> The problem we face above is that our authentication Plugin is being invoked BEFORE AppHost.OnPreExecuteServiceFilter

This method is executed before a Service is executed, the only other filters executed after this method but before a Service are [Service Filters](https://docs.servicestack.net/customize-http-responses#intercept-service-requests) and [Action Request Filter](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes#action-filter-attributes) attributes.

> Is there a different AppHost event that is fired after HttpContext.Current is populated

`HttpContext.Current` is populated by the ASP.NET Framework **before any ServiceStack Request** is executed which means it's always populated before any of the filters in a [ServiceStack Request pipeline](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations). The major Reason why it wouldn't be populated is if it was not accessed from an ASP.NET Request Worker Thread during a Request at runtime.

> and before Plugins are invoked?

This is impossible to answer as your question leaves out the vital information as to where exactly your plugin registers its custom handlers? i.e. What filters are executed before then is dependent on what request filter your plugin is registering. The order of which different handlers are executed during a request is documented in our [Order of Operations](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) page.

If you're referring to your plugins `Register(IAppHost)`, this like `AppHost.Configure()` is only executed once on Startup, you cannot access `HttpContext.Current` on Startup, it's only available during a Request. The Startup initialization logic is where your plugin would register its Request filters, e.g. `appHost.PreRequestFilters` or `appHost.GlobalRequestFilters` which are executed during a request before a ServiceStack Service is executed. Whereas the `*ResponseFilters` are executed after a Service is executed.

Now `HttpContext.Current` is for accessing an ASP.NET Request Context from a singleton context for when the Request context is not available however this is generally unnecessary in ServiceStack as every Request Filter can retrieve the ASP.NET Request Context from a ServiceStack `IRequest.OriginalRequest`, e.g:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) =>
{
    var aspReq = req.OriginalRequest as HttpRequestBase;
});
```

E,g. within a Service you can access `IRequest` from `base.Request`.

Comment: Most of this I was aware of, but thanks for the complete explanation. I fixed my problem by incorporating my initialization code into an IWebSessionManager and calling that directly from AppHostBase.OnPre|PostExecuteServiceFilter. I also moved our custom authentication code out of the plugin it was in and also just call that directly in AppHostBase.OnPreExecuteServiceFilter. With this setup I always have my HttpContext.Current.  Previously, my Auth plugin was being added to AppHostBase.GlobalRequestFilters and I assert that HttpContext.Current was null there. That was the root of my problem.

Comment: Further, I assert that it must be ServiceStack which under the covers is firing up a worker thread for the execution of AppHostBase.GlobalRequestFilters, which is the only explanation I can think of for why HttpContext.Current is null. It is definitely not my code! Alternatively ServiceStack might be firing up .NET-style async Tasks to execute GlobalRequestFilters. This is pure supposition on my part.

Comment: @KevinMacDonald If you added GlobalRequestFilters to the example ASP.NET Project you linked to and put a breakpoint you would've been able to check that `HttpContext.Current` is populated. It's unnecessary to make false assertions when all the source code is on GitHub, just link to the offending LOC you're claiming is spawning worker threads during a HTTP Request.

Comment: I currently have ServiceStack integrated with our classic ASP.NET app. The one app serves up ASPX as well as providing API calls to our angular clients. Do you think we should consider separating these concerns entirely? Pardon my false assertions. Bottom line, my problem is solved and you earned a paying customer in TeachTown.com. License purchases forthcoming shortly. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @KevinMacDonald I wouldn't split them unless you can identify clear benefits for doing so as multiple Hosts require additional code and ops maintenance overhead so you'll want enough productivity benefits for doing so, e.g. if they're maintained by different devs splitting into different projects should increase autonomy.